# Dynamic version of vb SelectSingleNode

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I know that with

```
book = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::bk:book[bk:author/bk:last-name='Atwood']", nsmgr);
```

it is possible to adress elements inside a xml file in a static manner.

Is there a way to use a similar scheme but with dynamic adressing. E.g. where'Atwood' is not a const string rather than a dynamic string.

Thanks for helping.

Btw: Example from [Microsoft help site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can't you just have a "format" string with placeholder and use (for example) `String.Format` to embed variable values and construct that "query" ?

Comment: Perfect Sehnsucht. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath expression that `SelectSingleNode()` receives is just a string. You should be able to use any approach applicable for constructing string dynamically in VB i.e simple string concatenation :

```
lastname = "Atwood"
query = "descendant::bk:book[bk:author/bk:last-name='" & lastname & "']"
book = root.SelectSingleNode(query, nsmgr)
```

... `String.Format()` as mentioned in the comment :

```
lastname = "Atwood"
query = "descendant::bk:book[bk:author/bk:last-name='{0}']"
book = root.SelectSingleNode(String.Format(query, lastname), nsmgr)
```

... or using new feature from VB 14, the *string interpolation* :

```
lastname = "Atwood"
query = $"descendant::bk:book[bk:author/bk:last-name='{lastname}']"
book = root.SelectSingleNode(query, nsmgr)
```

For reference :

- [MSDN: Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)
- [MSDN Magazine: 14 Top Improvements in Visual Basic 14](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)